# Problems accessing site master textbox value in another aspx form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I trying to access a textbox value from a aspx page from my site master but it doesn't seem to work and I get a  "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Appreciate any help given. Thanks!

In my site master code behind I am using the get accessor:
Thing is if I hardcode my value for my get accessor return value, I will have no problem

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage

{ 
 public string Text
  { 
  get
  {
  return TextBox1.Text
  }
 }
}
```

The aspx page which is trying to get the value from site master:

```
public partial class ProductSearch : System.Web.UI.Page
 {  
SiteMaster sm = new SiteMaster();

CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {       
try
 {           

if (sm.getSearch() != null)

     {
       search(sm.getSearch());
     }
  }          

catch (Exception ex)
{
Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the correction but the main issue still exist, hardcode works but drawing the value from textbox could not. Ok a little more info, maybe what I doing isn't right: I have a search textbox and search button in my site master which I use Server.Transfer to get to my search aspx page and the search aspx page will then get the value from my master page which is the search textbox for some linq queries.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create a new instance of `SiteMaster()`
So remove the line `SiteMaster sm = new SiteMaster();` from your `ProductSearch` class

Try this in your `Page_Load`

```
SiteMaster sm = Page.Master as SiteMaster;

if(sm!=null)
{
   if (sm.getSearch() != null)
   {
       search(sm.getSearch());
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SiteMaster MasterPage = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
```

That's how you will have to access the masterpage given that you have properly set up the masterpage.